# Jabref won't save files as .BST and LyX doesn't recognize .BIB

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, jabref

I'm having trouble with pushing a saved bibliography from Jabref to LyX, because Jabref doesn't have an option to save as a `.bst` file , and LyX doesn't want to recognize any other format than `.bst` (he does not recognize `.bib` files).

What should I do?

Comment: I think you are missing some key differences between `bst` and `bib` files. The `bst` file controls the formatting of the bibliography while the `bib` file contains the information about the sources you want to cite.

Comment: Bibliography databases *should* be `.bib` files, `.bst` files are bibliography styles, a different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments mention, a bibliography database should be a `.bib` file, so you shouldn't do anything else. A `.bst` file is a bibliography style file, that defines the formatting of the bibliography.

To add a bibliography database to a LyX document, after having done Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX Bibliography, click the *Add* button in the top right of window, then *Browse* in the new window that pops up, and locate your `.bib` file.

[image]